# Perl Array Dereference Problem with DBI::fetchall_arrayref

Tags: perl, reference, dbi

I'm a Perl newbie and am having issues with dereferencing an array that is a result of fetchall_arrayref in the DBI module:

```
my $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT home_room FROM $classlist";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
my $teachers = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
foreach my $teacher (@{$teachers}) {
    print $teacher;
}
```

Running this will print the reference instead of the values in the array.

However, when I run:

```
my $arrref = [1,2,4,5];
foreach (@{$arrref}) {
print "$_\n";
}
```

I get the values of the array.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to extract only the teacher column, you want to use:

```
my @teachers = @{$dbh->selectcol_arrayref($sql)};
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [doc](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#fetchall_arrayref)

> The fetchall_arrayref method can be
>   used to fetch all the data to be
>   returned from a prepared and executed
>   statement handle. **It returns a
>   reference to an array that contains
>   one reference per row**.

So in your example, `$teacher` is an ARRAY ref.
So you will need to loop through this array ref

```
foreach my $teacher (@{$teachers}) {
    foreach my $titem (@$teacher) {
        print $titem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`fetchall_arrayref` fetches *all* the results of the query, so what you're actually getting back is a reference to an array of arrays. Each row returned will be an arrayref of the columns. Since your query has only one column, you can say:

```
my $teachers = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
foreach my $teacher (@{$teachers}) {
    print $teacher->[0];
}
```

to get what you want.

See more:

[Arrays of arrays in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

Answer (score 5):

You have a reference to an array of rows. Each row is a reference to an array of fields.

```
foreach my $teacher_row (@$teachers) {
    my ($home_room) = @$teacher_row;
    print $home_room;
}
```

You would have seen the difference with [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper).

```
use Data::Dumper;
print(Dumper($teachers));
print(Dumper($arrref));
```

Answer (score 3):

`$sth->fetchall_arrayref` returns a reference to an array that contains one reference per row!
Take a look at DBI docs [here](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm).

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation of [DBI's fetchall_arrayref()](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#fetchall_arrayref):

> The fetchall_arrayref method can be
>   used to fetch all the data to be
>   returned from a prepared and executed
>   statement handle. It returns a
>   reference to an array that contains
>   one reference per row.

You're one level of indirection away:

```
my $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT home_room FROM $classlist";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
my $teachers = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
foreach my $teacher (@{$teachers}) {
    local $" = ', ';
    print "@{$teacher}\n";
}
```

The data structure might be a little hard to visualize sometimes.  When that happens I resort to `Data::Dumper` so that I can insert lines like this:

```
print Dumper $teacher;
```

I've found that sometimes by dumping the datastructure I get an instant map to use as a reference-point when creating code to manipulate the structure.  I recently worked through a real nightmare of a structure just by using Dumper once in awhile to straighten my head out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to dereference the returned structure:

```
@teachers = map { @$_->[0] } @$teachers;
```

Now you have a simple array of teachers.

Comment: I should mention that the @ before $_ will cause a "deprecated" warning in later versions of perl.  Just remove it to quiet this.